# Ruby gem command line application: creating a new session in bash

Tags: ruby, bash, command-line, rubygems

I'm trying to make my command line game to enter its own session (I don't know what the name is, but it looks like this) in `bash`:
[image: asciicast]

My first attempt looks like this:
[image: asciicast]
To accomplish the above, I use:
`system('clear')`
and escape key `\r\e` to rewrite lines above the cursor current position:
`print "\r\e[#{lines}A"`

What I want is when the command line application exits, the terminal change back to its previous state as if nothing happened, just like using `nano`, `less`, and many other command line tools.

How do you make a command line application do that with ruby?

Comment: I doubt that `nano` or `less` are written in Ruby, they are probably using low-level terminal functions.  Take a look at the curses library in Ruby.  Curses is a package which came from the writing the `vi` editor, and it (with the later ncurses) is a C library:  http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html

Comment: It might be simpler though to crate a new window in whatever GUI you are using, run the game in that, then close the window on exit.  The problem is that you want to undo the `clear` command, and you can't without using a windowing system.

Comment: I'll take a look at `curses`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're a looking for `rmcup` and `smcup` terminal capabilities.

```
print `tput smcup`
system('clear')
puts 'We are on alternate buffer'
puts 'press enter to switch back'
gets
print `tput rmcup`
```

You might also want to check ["Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?"](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite)

Comment: Awesome! But maybe I no longer need the `system('clear')`. This is exactly what I was looking for for now. Next time I'll probably use `curses`.