# Refreshing several lines in console while running

Tags: ruby, console

I want to make a program that looks like `top` or something similar that is updating several lines while running. The `system "clear"` in Mac OS Terminal.app in fact just scrolls current contents to the top, so if I scroll up, I see a lot of garbage.
It is somehow solvable via `curses`, but wouldn't it be overkill?

Comment: I guess `curses` is not overkill but the standard way. And it is in ruby core lib before 2.1 after all.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to make is called 'alternate screen'.
If you think `curses` is overkill for this, then maybe you can do this solution that has been given to me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845890/ruby-gem-command-line-application-creating-a-new-session-in-bash).

```
print `tput smcup`
puts 'We are on alternate screen'
# ...do something here...

# when you finished, do this to get out of the alternate screen
print `tput rmcup`
```

To rewrite several lines:

```
print "\r\e[#{number_of_lines_to_jump_up_to}A"
```

To delete previous characters:

```
print "\b"*number_of_characters_to_delete  # \b for backspace
```